# ScrollView doesn't scroll in AlertDialog

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

Why scrollView doesn't scroll in AlerDialog?

```
AlertDialog.Builder popupBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
sv.addView(ll);
for (int i=0;i<p.arr.size();i++){
    addPhoto(ll,p.arr.get(i));
}
popupBuilder.setView(sv);
popupBuilder.show();
```

So `addPhoto()` adds photos from array `arr` to `LinearLayout 'll'`

Comment: Have you required Scroll Horizontal or Vertical ?

Comment: Try to set `LayoutParams` for `LinearLayout`, It may do the work.

Comment: Try to set LinearLayout Orientation Like :  ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

Comment: Haresh, thanks. The problem was that ScrollView and LinearLayout had diferent orientations

Answer (score 0):

This is the layout in XML :

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
        <TextView />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

so Dynamically create the views in the same fashion with the views which ever is required

**Example 2**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textmsg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In Activity Class

```
LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourxmlfile, null);

TextView textview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textmsg);
textview.setText("Your really long message.");
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
alertDialog.setTitle("Title");  
//alertDialog.setMessage("Here is a really long message.");
alertDialog.setView(view);
alertDialog.setButton("OK", null);  
AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
alert.show();
```

`Note` that a ScrollView container can only have one child layout view. It is not possible, for example, to place a TextView and Button in a ScrollView without the LinearLayout.